# Laravel 7 Single row echo belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, view, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to display the value of `brand_id` column from `brands` table. Here's so far what I've done:

Car model

```
use App\Brand;

class Car extends Model
{
    public function brands(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class);
     }
}
```

Brand model

```
use App\Car;

class Brand extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'brand_name'
    ];

    public function cars(){
        return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
    }
}
```

ShowroomController

```
use App\Car;

class ShowroomController extends Controller
{
    public function details($name){
        $data = Car::where('car_name' , '=', $name)->first();

        if ($data == null){
            return redirect(route('index'));
        }else{
            return view('showroom')->with('detail', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

showroom view

```
@if (isset($detail))
  {{ $detail }} 
  {{ $detail->brands->brand_name }} //this doesn't work
@endif
```

Database

Brands table:

```
+----+------------+
| id | brand_name |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Brand1     | 
|  2 | Brand2     | 
+----+------------+
```

Cars table:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | car_name | brand_id |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | Car      |        1 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

I got lost on this point. Is this the right way to do the belongstomany and hasmany relationship? Thanks.

Comment: Try eager loading, you will get the brands data `$data = Car::with('brands')->where('car_name' , '=', $name)->first();`

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename_db.brand_car' doesn't exist (SQL: select `brands`.*, `brand_car`.`car_id` as `pivot_car_id`, `brand_car`.`brand_id` as `pivot_brand_id` from `brands` inner join `brand_car` on `brands`.`id` = `brand_car`.`brand_id` where `brand_car`.`car_id` in (1))

Comment: It shows this error.

Answer (score 2):

Change
`return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class)`;
 to 
`return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);` on the Car model

Also rename name function to `brand`. because car have only single brand
After it you can do `$detail->brand->brand_name`

Comment: Still didn't work, here the output: Trying to get property 'brand_name' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know it seems simple, thanks to @Imboom I got a hint to fix my problem. I made some changes on Car model:

1. `return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class);` to `return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class)`
2. rename name function to `brand`
3. Lastly, I just added `'brand_id'` to specify the column in `cars` table.

   `public function brand(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class,'brand_id');
   }`

In ShowroomController, I changed my return statement `detail` to `car`. See the code below:

```
public function details($name){
    $data = Car::where('car_name' , '=', $name)->first();

    if ($data == null){
        return redirect(route('index'));
    }else{
        return view('showroom')->with('car', $data);
    }
}
```

Then in showroom view, `$car->brand->brand_name` .

```
        @if (isset($car))
            {{ $car->car_name }}
            {{ $car->brand->brand_name }} // Output is Brand1
        @endif
```

Thank you!